# Selenium evaluating a subset of the DOM

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to evaluate the subset of a DOM element with selenium. First i find a parent element, after that I use FindElement on the parent to look for a child element. But I'm getting unexpected behavior here. The elements returned are not part of the parent.
I looked at the documentation but i don't get the results they do. https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/finders/

`var scavengeContainers = context.Driver.FindElements(ElementData.ScavengeOptions);`

This returns 4 elements, now I want to categorize them.

```
for (int i = 0; i < scavengeContainers.Count; i++)
{
    Log.Information("Getting scavenge data for {ele}",scavengeContainers[i].GetAttribute("innerHTML"));
    var readyScav = scavengeContainers[i].FindElement(By.XPath(ElementData.ReadyScavenge.Xpath));`

    if (scavengeContainers[i].FindElement(ElementData.WaitingScavenge) != null)
        scavengeModel.Levels[i] = new ScavengeLevel() { CompletionTime = GetScavengeQueueTime(scavengeContainers[i]), Id = i, Bought = true };
    else if (readyScav != null)
         scavengeModel.Levels[i] = new ScavengeLevel() { CompletionTime = DateTime.Now, Id = i, Bought = true };
    else
         scavengeModel.Levels[i] = new ScavengeLevel() { Bought = false, Id = i };
            }
```

I can verify the elements html with the print statement for innerHTML. This makes me sure that i have 4 different elements. However readyScav ID is always the same, even though it shouldn't be found in some of them. Is this just broken or am i using the wrong ? I have currently worked around it by looking for class in the innerHTML of the parent, instead of finding the element from the parent. However i still like to know what i am doing wrong here.

The find element code
`scavengeContainers[i].FindElement(ElementData.WaitingScavenge)`
is a bit diffrent from normal but this just translates to an extension function for readability.

```
public static IWebElement? FindElement(this IWebElement webElement, ElementData data)
{
    try
    {
        return webElement.FindElement(By.XPath(data.Xpath));
    }
        catch(NoSuchElementException)
    {
        Log.Debug("element {@elementData} was not found", data);
    }   
    return null;
}
```

Comment: show the locator that fails to look up the child elements as you expect

Comment: The issue is not that he wont find it, the issue is that it will find it even when its not there. If one of the elements in the array contains the locator then it will find it for all. Meaning it doesn't search the scavengeContainers[i] for children, it searches the dom again. Printing the innerHTML however does give me unique html as i see it when looking at the website.

Comment: So what is the XPath you are using

Comment: "//*[contains(@class,\"act_btn\")]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't start your locator from `//` when you look up from the specific element. When you do so, the search context is ignored and the element is getting searched from the top of the DOM.

Try `.//*[contains(@class,\"act_btn\")]`